# Salami Slice vs Russian Doll XSD Validation in C#

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I noticed that if I use the *Salami Slice* XSD Schema format, the **XML Validator** in **C#** works correctly.

But, if I use the same **XSD** in *Russian Doll* format, the **XML Validator** fails.

Note that in both cases I generate the `xsdclass.cs` using **xsd.exe** provided by Visual Studio.

Someone can exlpain why? I lost 30 minutes to understand it and I got a headache.

---

> Russian Doll format (not working):

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="kyactusprofile">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="username"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="userid"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="useDefaultFolder"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="autoAcceptDownloads"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="visible"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

> Same XSD in Salami Slice (working):

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="userid" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="useDefaultFolder" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="autoAcceptDownloads" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="visible" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="kyactusprofile">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="username"/>
        <xs:element ref="userid"/>
        <xs:element ref="useDefaultFolder"/>
        <xs:element ref="autoAcceptDownloads"/>
        <xs:element ref="visible"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

The errors I get are:

```
Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred.Impossibile trovare informazioni sullo schema per l'elemento 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:schema'. Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred.Impossibile trovare informazioni sullo schema per l'attributo 'attributeFormDefault'. Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred.Impossibile trovare informazioni sullo schema per l'attributo 'elementFormDefault'. Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred.Impossibile trovare informazioni sullo schema per l'elemento 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:element'.
```

Comment: Can you actually deserialize data with working version, or do you just not get a validation error?

Comment: Are you getting any exception or other error message? If so, could you please include it in the question?

Comment: I am able to deserialize/serialize data with both formats but using other XSD validator. The WPF C# XmlSchemaSet works fine with SalamiSlice only.

Comment: I get no errors, simply it says that the XML is not valid agains the XSD.

Comment: How does it say this; what's the exact message?

Comment: For example: Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred.Couldn't fint informations about the schema for the attribute 'type'.

Answer (score 0):

The message suggests to me (from my minimal Italian) that it's complaining about the attributes attributeFormDefault and elementFormDefault not being declared, and this suggests in turn that it's trying to validate the schema, not the instance document. So I think it's something to do with the way you are invoking the validator.